# How to make clicking a Button inside a ListBoxItem select the item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `ListBox` defined as follows:

```xml
<ListBox
    DisplayMember="Name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PeopleDataTemplate}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Name="listOfPeople">
</ListBox>
```

The `Person` class contains two properties:

```cs
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

XAML:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PeopleDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image
                Width="75"
                Height="75"
                Source="{Binding Picture}">
            </Image>
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.AddCommand , ElementName=main}" Content="Add" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

If I click the `Image`, the `ListBoxItem` gets selected but if I click the `Button`, the `ListBoxItem` does not get selected. Why?

Comment: *"The listBoxItem is defined like this"* - this doesn't looks like listbox item. Another thing: `dxe:` namespace is likely to be devexpress, consider to add correct library tag to the question. I've got a feeling your native language is not English (questions you are asking are pretty unclear). There are localized SO sites (e.g. [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)), consider to ask question there.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to add corresponding triggers to the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` to delegate focus:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why doesn't the item get selected?**

**TL;DR: because the mouse down event is handled by the `Button` and never reaches the `ListBoxItem`.**

What triggers the `IsSelected` property on each `ListBoxItem` is the `MouseRightButtonDownEvent` routed event [declared on `UIElement`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Generated/UIElement.cs,3329) whose handling is overriden by `ListBoxItem` [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ListBoxItem.cs,267). However, this `MouseDownEvent` is a [bubbling routed event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview), meaning that it climbs up the visual tree until marked as *handled* by something on its way:

- If you click your `Image`: `Image` receives `MouseDown` but does not handle it. It bubbles up to `StackPanel`, same story. Bubbles up to `ListBoxItem`. Bingo, it is handled there and calls a method on the parent `ListBox` that marks the item as selected.
- If you click your `Button` however: the `Button` receives the `MouseDown` event and immediately marks it as `Handled` [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/Primitives/ButtonBase.cs,419). The event propagation is stopped and the event never bubbles up to the `ListBoxItem` which never gets selected.

**How to get around this?**

*The MVVM way*

In your `AddCommand` implementation, add some code to change the `IsSelected` property to `true`. Since you bind to `IsSelected`, this will select your `ListBoxItem`.

*The XAML way*

Add a `Click` event handler to the `Button` to manually mark its parent `ListBoxItem` as `Selected`.

As pointed out by @Sinatr, you could also react to focus events to select any item that gets the focus. Subscribe to the `GotFocus` event of each of your `StackPanel` for example and [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) the parent `ListBox` (on which you call `UnselectAll()`) and find the parent `ListBoxItem` (on which you call `Focus()`).

Comment: After reading your answer I was able to understand the problem of OP. Just adding a bit: if button is inside listbox item template, then it will be also possible to set focus on it without changing listbox selection (which is looking weird). Instead of proposed change to a command a better way is to simply handle focus: anything inside should select parent listbox item on focus. This can be organized as reusable attached behavior.

Comment: okay, without getting into attached behavior for now, how would you go in this case? Subscribe to an OnFocus event for example?

Comment: By subscribing to `GotFocus` event and [finding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/636383/1997232) parent listbox (to call `UnselectAll()`) and listbox item (to call its `Focus()`).